# the reading of this kanji combination 炊煙 and meaning of 人家

Tags: kanji

I have encountered another sentence while translating some text of Japanese history
The sentence is:

> 人家の竈（かまど）から炊煙が立ち上っていないことに気づいて租税を免除します。 jinka no kamado kara 炊煙 ga
> tachiagatteinai koto ni kidzuite sozei wo menjo shimasu.

So I have these words:

> 人家 jinka
>
> 炊煙

I have problem with the meaning of jinka. Does this refer to houses and buildings in that period of history?
In case of 炊煙. As I found out 炊 taku means cooking and 煙 kemu means fume and smoke. So Do I presume well if I think they mean "fumes and smokes deriving from cooking"? And how can we pronounce it?

Comment: http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E7%82%8A%E7%85%99&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss

Answer (score 2):

As snailplane points out, you can find 炊煙{すいえん} in the dictionary. It's the smoke that comes from cooking, presumably an older word since all the definitions refer specifically to smoke from a かまど, but as your rather astute skills of deduction have ascertained, it is in fact smoke from cooking.

人家 is not exclusively a historical word. It refers to houses where people live and is used today.